# I tried to create a second model, but when I try to put it in my html page nothing appears

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

When I try to create the second model my html page comes out blank. I tried to copy the first model but I don't think I succeeded. Is the error in views.php?

This is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from colorfield.fields import ColorField

# Create your models here.
class Aziende(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prezzo = models.FloatField()
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    nome_color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Aziende"

class Materie(models.Model):
    immagine = models.ImageField()
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    prezzo = models.FloatField()
    descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    nome_color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Materie"
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Aziende
from .models import Materie
admin.site.register(Aziende)
admin.site.register(Materie)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Aziende
from .models import Materie
# Create your views here.
def Borsa(request):
    Borsa = Aziende.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Borsa/Home.html', {'Borsa': Borsa},)

def Materia(request):
    Materia = Materie.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Borsa/Home.html', {'Materie': Materia},)
```

home.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for Materie in Materia %}
    <div class="col"><br>
      <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="{{ Materie.immagine.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="title" style="color: {{Materie.nome_color}}" >{{Materie.nome}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{Materie.descrizione}}</p>
        <p class="card-text fst-italic text-primary">Valore Attuale: €{{Materie.prezzo}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Investici!</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!! (I did all the necessary migrations)